# How do I check the contents of a TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox. In that textbox I write Human. Then I click a button, and if the word is human, then on a richtextbox, the word human will appear.

Here's the code I've tried.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox4.Text)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "human";
        }
    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = textBox4.Text;
    }
```

I tried making the textbox into a string so I could use it in the if statement, but it didn't work, so instead I used texbox4.text, but it is still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do with this piece of code,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textBox1.Text =="human")
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```